# How do I use a variable declared in a ##_helper file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to execute a before save definition like so in my `Route.rb` file. (@current_user.email is causing the error)

```
      class Route < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save { |route| route.created_by = @current_user.email }

end
```

But I get this error,

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

But I can use it just fine in my `_header.html.erb` Like so:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <%= @current_user.email %>
    <span class="caret"></span>
```

`@current_user` is described in my `sessions_helper` like so:

```
module SessionsHelper

    def sign_in(user)
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
        current_user = user
    end

    def signed_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    def current_user=(user)
        @current_user
    end

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
    end

    def current_user?(user)
        user == current_user
    end

    def sign_out
        current_user = nil
        cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    end
end
```

Why am I not able to execute this `before_save` without getting that error? Thanks guys.

Comment: Do you get the same errors if you access `@current_user` via the `current_user` method (`self.created_by = current_user.email` without the `@`)?

Comment: `undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Route:0x007fc385eda0a8>`

Comment: You might want to try this gem? https://github.com/house9/clerk - sets creator and updater on models automatically

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, your `SessionsHelper` looks similar [to that of The Rails Tutorial](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb).  Given that, I think you have some issues with your `current_user` and `current_user=` methods as they seem to be doing the opposite thing.  They should probably be:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end

def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end
```

**Edit**

[The model should not know about controller or helper methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10190995/567863), so you might want to set `@route.created_by = current_user.email` somewhere in the relevant controller before you save the object.

Comment: Yeah it is the same one from the rails tutorial, but it still isn't working I did the fixes

Comment: I don't get why I can use it in my `_header.html.erb` just fine but not in my Route.rb file

Comment: Have you added `include SessionsHelper` to the `ApplicationController`?

Comment: Yes I did, `include SessionsHelper`

Comment: I tried changing it to   `before_save { |route| route.created_by = @current_user.email }` but still nothing

Comment: You probably need to access `@current_user` via the helper methods `current_user` and `current_user=` rather than directly by calling `@current_user` or `@current_user = ...`.

Comment: Nope still `undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Strange.  Is your app open source?  If so, do you have the current code on Github so that others can clone it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25990/discussion-between-xcritics-and-paul-fioravanti)