# undefined method `fragment_for' for nil:NilClass on render partial with cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, partials

I have this piece of code in a partial on some code for rails 2.3.14:

```
<% cache "some_partial_#{some_id}" do %>
....
<% end %>
```

Works fine when rendering it in a view but I get:

```
undefined method `fragment_for' for nil:NilClass
```

when I try to do this in a model:

```
 ActionView::Base.new("app/views").render(:partial => "home/temp"}
```

I can see the issue occuring in actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_view/helpers/cache_helper.rb:35

```
 def cache(name = {}, options = nil, &block)
    @controller.fragment_for(output_buffer, name, options, &block)
 end
```

I'm not sure what exactly it expects to find in @controller.

Answer (score 0):

In short: don't render partials from models - they should contain only business-logic. Error occurs since cache invokes controller object which you don't have initialized since you are bypassing view rendering logic here.

UPDATE:

The only way i see it is to get controller instance and pass it as param. How to get controller instance inside model is up to you. I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419120/ruby-on-rails-access-controller-variable-from-model) could be helpful Try

```
ActionView::Base.new("app/views", {}, @your_controller_instance).render(:partial => "home/temp")
```

Comment: While I do agree that it's incredibly bad practice to render from models, it's one of those situations where I don't really have a choice since a lot of this big app relies on that function working like that. I tried overriding def cache ... and placing a controller ||= ApplicationController but as expected ApplicationController doesn't really define fragment_for anywhere, so I guess it's waiting for something else in that @controller, just not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to add:

```
include ActionController::Caching
```

to your class.