# render a partial inside a model rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I understand advice available on the net to never, ever, ever render in a model, for this case I need do it

```
 class Order
    def canceled_order_message(order)
            admin = User.find_or_create_by(email: "myemail")
            message = Message.new(subject: I18n.t(".buyer_has_canceled_the_order"), 
                      body: "#{render_to_string :partial => 'users/messages/templates/sent_by_admin/canceled_order', :locals => {:order => order}}")
            message.send_message
            message.save
    end
 end
```

I need render inside message body attribute:

```
render_to_string :partial => 'users/messages/templates/sent_by_admin/canceled_order
```

How can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: This code really does belong in your `Order` controller, or better yet in a Resque or Sidekiq background job (since you're sending a message which could take some time). What benefit do you get from placing it in the model?

Comment: Now is working. I have fixed the logic and now the render partial is called from a helper method. Is a delayed job task, runed in model like `def self.canceled_order_message(order, partial) ...end`. I send the partial as parameter to this method from my controller with `Order.delay(queue: "order", priority: 2, run_at: 2.minutes.from_now).expired_message(order, canceled_partial(order))` and now is working fine :D :Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check my answer here:

[undefined method `fragment_for' for nil:NilClass on render partial with cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685782/undefined-method-fragment-for-for-nilnilclass-on-render-partial-with-cache/12686110#12686110)

I think that could be useful.

P.S. Horrible idea, please rethink your architecture.

Comment: Seconded. You should never ever be rendering things from your model.

Comment: I have refactored the logic and now is working well. Thank you very much!