# how to call action from model to controller in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to call 'checking' action from post model.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
     after_commit :testing
     def testing
         @id = "#{self.id}"
         puts @id
         checking # call action to controller 
     end
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
def checking
  puts "not Working"
end
```

I am trying to achieve the above, whereas it is not getting called.

Comment: you should be calling model functions from controller, models should not be aware of controller logics

Comment: What is the reason your doing that? Explain more what are really what to do, because it seems that you are just lost.

Comment: The models should not know about the controller logic. Maybe you can refactor and set some variables from controller to model like it is described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2420015/1108032)

Comment: What exactly you want? Why you exactly need to call a controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by instantiating the controller.

```
SomeController.new.some_action
```

However it is `Not Recommended` as your model logic should be independent of your controller logic. Your model should follow [Single-responsibility Principle](http://jjbohn.info/blog/2014/07/28/single-responsibility-principle-a-solid-week/).

> A class should have only a single responsibility.

You might need some common logic for controller and models or some service!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As it was said: the models should not know about controller.

Depending on the reason,

1. you can define `checking` in model and from `Controller` just call this method for current `Post`.
2. if something should be set from `Controller` and checked in `Model` , you can use the approach defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419120/ruby-on-rails-access-controller-variable-from-model/2420015#2420015)

Answer (score 0):

As many (or all) other said, you shouldn't call a Controller action from a Model. If you are saving/destroying and object from a Controller and you want to check is commit was called, you can do it in the controller, after saving or destroying.

posts_controller.rb

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
  if @post.save
    checking
  end
end

def checking
  puts "Is is working"
end
```

If this is not what you want, because you are specifically interested in the commit callback, you can change the code to this:

posts_controller.rb

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
  @post.save
  if @post.commmited?
    checking
  end
end

def checking
  puts "Is is working"
end
```

And add some logic to your Model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :commit_performed

  #unset the commit_performed attribute on first callbacks
  before_destroy :unset_commit
  before_validation :unset_commit

  #set the commit_performed attribute after commit
  after_commit :set_commit

  def unset_commit
    @commit_performed = false
  end

  def set_commit
    @commit_performed = true
  end

  def commited?
    @commit_performed
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not be calling a controller action from a model. That's not how even controller methods are called. If you want to trigger an action, it should be either written as a target of a view form or input method, or as a redirect through another controller method itself. If you really want this action to be triggered (if you want the message after a record is saved to a listener url), I'd suggest using a lib such as `HTTP::Net` or a gem like `HTTParty` to trigger a call to the action, with its url or rails url_helper. That too, is not suggested, and/or is not the way to operate things in rails.

Comment: There's a lot of work around in his case. He is not really need a gem, he need to think what are he really want to do.

Comment: Thank u guys.this is more helpful for me.